# Why don't some cursor themes show up in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, themes, cursor

I have many cursor themes on my system that don't show up in GNOME's list of themes, yet work fine in other desktop environments (XFCE, LXDE, KDE, etc). What can I do to get these to show up? . Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still can't find a fix, but I have a feeling this one won't get far as a bug report in GNOME (it seems to be related to older themes or something, and GNOME is wierd).

So, in light of that, here is the solution I found (not perfect, but at least I can use the theme I want).

- press alt+f2, type “gconf-editor” and run it.
- navigate (no need for a map here) to /desktop/gnome/peripherals/mouse
- double click on the cursor theme entry
- type the name of the cursor theme you want to use
- close the editor
- you may have to log out and in again, depending on your window manager
- if you are using compiz, the above may be necessary to see the changes in full, even though the theme may appear to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it handles pointers or not, but you could try a GTK appearance app like LXAppearance in lieu of the Gnome theme app.