# Why do most window managers fail to show a custom cursor correctly?

Tags: xorg, customization, window-manager, cursor

## Please note: I am not looking for a fix.

However, I want to know why most Window managers ignore my choice of cursor theme and show the default cursor no matter what.

Is there a problem with the architecture of X that causes this?

[Why don't some cursor themes show up in GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/q/30955/1992)
Is not the same question.

Comment: Which window managers?

Comment: @function gala, compiz, mutter, metacity, xfwm4 (IIRC), enlightenment...

Comment: You may know this already, but as a comparison, custom cursors in KDE work fine. There's even a system-setting page to select which cursor you want.

Comment: @Sparhawk yes, I know that, but that doesn't help answer the question.

Comment: I thought it might be helpful as a comparison, since it suggests there is something specific to KDE that allows custom cursors. Also, it implies that what is common in KDE and the other window managers is not to blame for the lack of functionality. i.e. it's probably not X-related.

Comment: @Sparhawk okay I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

Edit this file /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme and type the cursor theme then logout and login again, it should work on all windows.

Comment: I asked for the reason lol...

Comment: @RolandiXor That does fix the problem though as it sets the default cursor theme to the theme of your choice.

Comment: @mchid I'm aware of the fix. I'm asking for the cause.